Pydantic validation error for a value that cannot be None. It is none
I get this error:
 Value error, Status cannot be None [type=value_error, input_value=<JobStatus.PENDING: 'PENDING'>, input_type=JobStatus]

on the from_orm method of this class:
"""
Job model
"""

@dataclass(config=ConfigDict(from_attributes=True))
class Job:
    """
    Job model
    """

    status: JobStatus = JobStatus.PENDING
   
    @field_validator("status")
    def on_status_update(cls, new_status: JobStatus):
        """
        Update the status of the job
        """
        if cls.status == JobStatus.DONE and new_status == JobStatus.ERROR:
            raise InvalidStatusError("Cannot pass status from DONE to ERROR")

        cls.status = new_status

    @field_validator("status")
    def check_status_not_none(cls, value):
        if value is None:
            raise ValueError("Status cannot be None")
        return value

    
    @staticmethod
    def from_orm(job: JobTable) -> "Job":
        """
        Convert a JobTable to a Job
        """
        domain_job = Job(
           ...
            status=JobStatus(job.status.name),
        ...
            job_id=job.job_id,
        )
        return domain_job

and the enum declaration is:
from enum import Enum


class JobStatus(Enum):
    """
    Job status
    """

    PENDING = "PENDING"
    RUNNING = "RUNNING"
    ERROR = "ERROR"
    DONE = "DONE"
    PARTIAL = "PARTIAL"

and
from enum import Enum

class PostgresJobStatusEnum(Enum):
    PENDING = "PENDING"
    RUNNING = "RUNNING"
    ERROR = "ERROR"
    DONE = "DONE"
    PARTIAL = "PARTIAL"

The code above is the last iteration. I have changed passing the status value to the status name, and adding a method to check that the status is none.
